Janitor opens door to find rest of building obliterated
There is a shot of a janitor running a floor waxing machine in a highrise building. There is some loud noise & major rumbling. The power goes out & he is in total darkness. There is a door at the end of the hall with daylight showing underneath. He opens the door & sees that the rest of the building (& many others) have been completely obliterated. The camera pans back & shows him standing in the open doorway.

That sounds like a scene from The Day After Tomorrow (2004).  Someone on a forum describes it like this:

there was a janitor cleaning the floors. [...] The janitor notices a lot of light coming from underneath the door so he goes and opens it. Now, the amount of light coming from underneath the door made it look like there was a spotlight pointed at it from the other side and when the janitor opens it that half of the building is gone.

EDIT:  The janitor opens the door at the beginning of this YouTube clip.

That sounds right. Thank you much!
